# ext4 drive takes forever to ls?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I've had an external HDD formatted in ext4 for a while. For some reason, it's started to take forever to list directories. Sometimes just running `ls /mount/point/of/drive` takes minutes, sometimes that directory will `ls` fine, but not directories in it, etc. Could this be a sign that the drive it getting old, or even about to fail? Copying files is as fast as ever over USB 2.

Comment: How many files/directories are in these directories that take a long time to `ls`?

Comment: Anything in the kernel logs (or in `dmesg` output)?

Comment: @Patrick some up to a few hundred, but the root of the drive has 4 files and 2 directories or something like that, shouldn't take this long

Answer (score 1):

#### Filesystem diagnostics

I would run an `e2fsck` on the disk to start. You'll need to run this readonly against it. Also check out the disk using either `hdparm` or `sdparm`.

```
$  hdparm -tT /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 Timing cached reads:   3884 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1941.51 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:   46 MB in  0.62 seconds =  74.40 MB/sec
```

From my experience slowness as you're describing would mean that the drive is most likely starting to have physical failures.

#### What else?

Given the type of issues you're seeing I would also try running something such as [HDAT](http://www.hdat2.com/download.html) or [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) (Commercial) against the disk to see if it reports any physical failures as well.

You might also want to try booting from some other bootable media and running `smartctl` to see if there are any SMART errors.

For example:

```
$ smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

#### References

- [e2fsck man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck)
- [sdparm tutorial](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sdparm.html)
- [sdparm man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sdparm)
- [hdparm man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm)

Comment: If the physical failure is worn out ("bad") blocks, `e2fsck -c` should take care of it, but you may loose data.